# Handlebars lookup helper to build dynamic tables

Tags: javascript, html, templates, handlebars.js

I would like to build a dynamic table using handlebars. I *think* I have to use lookup helper to achieve my wanted result. I am having some trouble using the lookup helper and the documentation is rather poor.

An example of my object looks like this:

```
{
headers:[
  0:"name",
  1:"brand",
  2:"type",
  3:"rating",
  4:"edited"
]
tableContent:[
  0:{
     contentName:{
        name:"Fanta",
        brand:"Coca-Cola Company",
        type:"Soda",
        rating:"3",
        edited:"2017-05-24"}
    }
]
}
```

Handlebars template:

```
<script id="itemTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <table id="table" class="bordered highlight centered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        {{#headers}}
        <th>{{this}}</th>
        {{/headers}}
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        {{#each tableContent}}
        {{#each headers}}
        <td>{{lookup ../contentName headers}}</td>
        {{/each}}
        {{/each}}
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>
```

The reason I can't simply do `<td> contentName.name </td>` and so on, is that the user can create their own columns in the database, so I would have no way of knowing the property names beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

With a [little modification](https://ember-twiddle.com/081464ff4b93d4545eacaadd1f87b5d4?openFiles=routes.application.js%2C) in your object, you can do it with [ember-contextual-table](https://github.com/tubitak-bilgem-yte/ember-contextual-table).

Here is [the twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/081464ff4b93d4545eacaadd1f87b5d4?openFiles=templates.components.simple-table.hbs%2C) for you.

Sample code:

```
{{#data-table data=data.tableContent as |t|}}
  {{#each data.headers as |columnName|}}
    {{t.column propertyName=columnName name=columnName}}
  {{/each}}
{{/data-table}}
```

**Updated**

But if you want to make your code run, here it is:

```
  <table class="bordered highlight centered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        {{#each data.headers as |header|}}
        <th>{{header}}</th>
        {{/each}}
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        {{#each data.tableContent as |c|}}
          {{#each data.headers as |h|}}
          <td>{{get c h}}</td>
          {{/each}}
        {{/each}}
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Have a look at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/867e9e20e994604f3673ae6fe8f74f76?openFiles=templates.components.simple-table.hbs%2C)

Comment: Thank you! Guess I have some reading to do! Am I just not understanding how the lookup helper works, or doesn't it work for the purpose I need?

Comment: Instead of lookup, use `get`. Then you can make it work with a little modification in your object. Have a look at the updated code of my post.

Comment: I did not, I realized I had mistagged my post with ember, as such i'm still trying to get it to work with handlebars.js. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: There is no "get" in handlebars.js though? Or is just one of many undocumented features?

Comment: Aha, that's my mistake, sorry. You can define it with `Handlebars.registerHelper('get', function(obj, key) {
  return obj[key];
});`

Comment: Still not getting any output. I tried `{{#each tableContent as |c|}} {{#each headers as |h|}} <td>{{get ../contentName h}}</td> {{/each}} {{/each}}` as well as the code in your comment, but no luck.

Comment: `{{get c h}}` ?

Comment: Yes I tried that as well. Just getting an empty table.